# R histogram from already summarized count

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a really huge file, thus I had to count frequencies for histogram generation outside the R.

Couldn't find the correct answer in already existing threads. Everything I tried led me to bar plot or failure (even R's exceptions didn't let it plot as histogram the way I tried)

file looks like (it's tab delimited):

```
freq    cov
394104974   1
387288861   3
141169009   4
105488813   2
60039934    6
45109486    5
26318120    7
9691068 8
7532886 9
3973434 10
```

it has sth like 3k lines.
How can I plot this with ggplot2 as a nice histogram? (cov column holds x axis values)

Cheers,
Irek

Comment: What's wrong with a bar plot?

Comment: Is `cov` continuous or discrete? If it is discrete then you want a bar plot.

If you really want a histogram you could use something like `rep` to create data frame with the value of `cov` repeated by the value of `freq`, and then create your histogram

Comment: area under histogram = 1

Comment: it is discrete value. Hmm I see. Well I was somewhat pressed to get a histogram out of it.

Comment: You could simply scale the frequencies yourself, if you want the "area" under them to be 1.

Comment: @joran Since `cov` represents discrete categories, a bar plot is more appropriate than a histogram (since you can't have counts between values of `cov`). See `geom_bar()` if you want to use ggplot2 for plotting. However, you can easily make a bar plot of the summarized data using something like `barplot(data[, 1])`.

Comment: @EllisValentiner I don't know why you directed that at me. I was the the first one to suggest that they just stick with bar plots.

Comment: @joran my bad I wasn't paying attention. It should have been to Irek oops

Comment: I get my mistake for trying to use histogram for discrete values. Thanks for help

Comment: @EllisValentiner No worries, I was just confused, that's all.